# Hibernate Retrieving sorted Objects from database

Tags: hibernate

I want to write a random function which give n th of a sorted list that n is random.
I am using hibernate and **I don't want sort tables in DB**.
How can I retrieving sorted Objects from database without using @Sort @OrderBy on top of columns.

Comment: Can you explain this "I don't want sort tables in DB" vs "retrieving sorted Objects from database"? You still want to do sorting on db but without mention annotations? Sort -> Collection sort (Java level sorting), OrderBy -> same as sql order by, sorting on db.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to sort tables in the DB so you cannot retrieve sorted items. You can, however, simply sort them programatically after retrieving them.

Lets assume you have a `Collection<Widget>`, where `Widget` is:

```
class Widget {
    //id, version etc
    private String name;

   //getters and setters
}
```

And a query something like

```
final List<Widget> result = /*create query*/.list();
```

Now all you need to do to take the `n`th sorted item is:

```
Optional<Widget> nth = result.stream().
        sorted(Comparator.comparing(Widget::getName)).
        skip(n - 1).
        findAny();
```

If there are at least `n` items then `nth.get` will return it. Otherwise it will throw a `NoSuchElementException`.